# Automatically printing attachments in outlook subfolder using Powershell and MAPI

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am trying to figure a way of printing attachments that land in a subfolder of outlook. I have got as far as a script which extracts them to a folder, but i am wondering if i should power shell print from that folder, or if there is just a way of printing them as they get sent to that folder first.

```
    #file path
$filepath = “c:\tests\”


#set outlook to open
$o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$n = $o.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)


#you'll get a popup in outlook at this point where you pick the folder you want to scan
#$f = $n.pickfolder()
$Account = $n.Folders | ? { $_.Name -eq 'mymailaccount@company.com' };
$Inbox = $Account.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'Inbox' };
$f = $Inbox.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'colour' };

#now loop through them and grab the attachments
$f.Items | foreach {
    $_.attachments | foreach {
    Write-Host $_.filename
    $a = $_.filename
    $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $a)) | Foreach-Object { Start-Process -FilePath $_.FullName –Verb Print }
  }
}
```

this extracts the attachments but doesnt print.

This does print that folder:

```
Dir c:\tests\*.* | Foreach-Object { Start-Process -FilePath $_.FullName –Verb Print }
```

I have these two scripts but am unsure how i would either print each attachment from script 1 or combine script 1 and 2, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't look like saveasfile outputs anything, so the subsequent pipeline wouldn't have any file objects to work with.

Answer (score 0):

SaveAsFile doesn't return the filename, so you should be able to just have a statement after that which does the printing.

```
$_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $a)) 
Start-Process -FilePath (Join-Path $filepath $a) –Verb Print }
```